# How to combine my data with worldclim data

Tags: r, geospatial, data-extraction

Here are two questions:
1. My data has many variables including 2nd and 3rd columns of longitude and latitude. For prediction purpose, I want to add to my data the bioclim info from "worldclim" of the raster package. I could use the following code to extract bioclim values for my data.

```
wc <- getData('worldclim', var='bio', res=10)
mydatac<-extract(wc, mydata[,2:3])
```

But mydatac only has the coordinates and bioclim values. Should I simply bind as below to combine mydata with the bioclim info? How do I know the bioclim values are aligned with the longitude/latitude in the final result? Thank you.

```
cbind.data.frame(mydata,mydatac)
```

2. Is it possible to similarly extract USA crime data by longitude/latitude in R? I haven't find any useful package yet. Thank you.

Comment: The `aggregate()` and `match()` functions might be of use.

Comment: Providing a minimal reproducible example of your `mydata` improves chances to get an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extract` output a dataframe where observations are in the same order than in your original dataset. So, yes, you can `cbind` both dataframes.

```
data.frame(mydata, mydatac)
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. I was thinking of merge back but if the order are the same for both dataset bind saves much more time.